# how to resolve group by error query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to query the following but its not executing

```
SELECT
  MAX(time) as last_time,
  column_A,
  column_B
from
  table_1
WHERE
  column_c='foo'
```

Its replying with the following error message

> ERROR:  column "column_A" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function

However its replying the following query correctly

```
SELECT MAX(time) as last_time from table_1 WHERE column_c='foo'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment in the other answer you say you want only one value:

```
SELECT
  "time" as last_time,
  column_A,
  column_B
from table_1
WHERE column_c = 'foo'
order by "time" desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ref [PostgreSQL 8.0 Group By](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

All columns that are not in an aggregate function MUST be in the group by
clause if there is any column in an aggregate function.

```
SELECT MAX(time) as last_time, column_A, column_B  
FROM table_1 WHERE column_c='foo' 
GROUP BY column_A, column_B
```

Comment: You didn't explain your answer, try adding some context so the person can learn something.

Comment: Thanks boss...its working....I will tick it after few minutes. but I am facing another problem. I wanted to get only the last_time. That means the query will return only one value. but its returning more than one value.

Comment: you cant get one value because u are using col1 and col2 in select expression , it will always return max time for all unique col1 and col2

Can you plese tell us what output you want??? .

Comment: @Avi :- thanx avi for your comment, you save my time. Md. Azizul Alam:- can you give us a sample data with expected o/p